# Incorporating charls into a MacOS application

Tags: xcode, macos

Charls is an implementation of the JPEG-LS lossless and near-lossless coder/decoder. I downloaded the source code, built it in Xcode, and ran it on MacOS. From a few tests I ran, it seems to be reliable and very fast.

Now I want to incorporate charls into my application. I added the static library libcharls.a to my Xcode project and added the header file charls.h. When I try to do a build, I get the error: library not found for -lcharls. I then added a path to libcharls.a in the Library Search Paths of the Build Settings for the Project in Xcode. Still get the same error. Anyone have suggestions for getting this to build? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: adding the path to libcharls.a in Library Search Paths does fix the problem, but you only add the *path*, but not the file libcharls.a.